# Update column rows based on rows in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataset as given below in R.  I am trying to update the empty cell in the Description column for '0' values in column Value.

```
 Criteria     Value   Description 
 Success       0                                      
 Success      21      look up
 Success      20      repeat
 Success      19      What is this
 Success      18      Transition
 Success      17      Program
 Success       0
```

I would appreciate any help to solve this.  The output that I am trying to get is given below:

```
 Criteria     Value   Description 
 Success       0      TEST                             
 Success      21      look up
 Success      20      repeat
 Success      19      What is this
 Success      18      Transition
 Success      17      Program
 Success       0      TEST
```

Comment: You want to fill the column with what? Also provide the output of `dput(yourdataframe)`. Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to improve quality of your question.

Comment: mydf$Description[mydf$Value == 0] <- "TEST"

Comment: @Masoud:  Thanks for sharing the link.  This is a good article; will take input and reframe my question to be reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options:

**Base R - Option 1**

```
mydf$Description[mydf$Value == 0] <- "TEST"
```

**Base R - Option 2**

```
mydf$Description <- ifelse(mydf$Value == 0, "TEST", mydf$Description)
```

**dplyr - [if_else()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/if_else)**

```
library("dplyr")
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(Description = if_else(Value == 0, "TEST", Description))
```

**dplyr - [case_when()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/case_when)**

Useful when a number of if statement need to be evaluated.

```
library("dplyr")
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(
  Description = case_when(
    Value == 0 ~ "TEST",
    TRUE ~ Description
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had some issue with the Description since they were "factors" in my case.  Had to convert them to characters before using this.  Appreciate your multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Could use an ifelse() statement.

Assuming your dataframe is called "dataset", you can use an ifelse() statement to check the Value column for 0.  If it is a 0, it will input the value "TEST" in the Description column.  If it is not a 0 (else), then it will just input what value is already there in the column.

```
 dataset$Description <- ifelse(dataset$Value == 0, 
                               "TEST" , 
                               dataset$Description)
```

Comment: `ifelse` is quiet inefficiency, maybe try  `dataset$Description[dataset$Value==0]='Test'` or `dataset$Description[dataset$Value%in%0]='Test'`